# Handling Drop Down using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am facing issues with handling a trivial scenario during automation. I need to select a specific option using Protractor. I am passing the index of the option that I want to select, and then clicking on that to select it. However, my `click()` method errors out stating the `click()` method is undefined on that index.

Here is what I am trying to do - in my `selectElements.js` file, the dropdown method is defined as

```
const selectElement={}

selectElement.selectElementDropdown =function(element,index,milliseconds){
   console.log("Selecting element by drop down","OK");

   element.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options){

   options[2].click(); 
  //here index 2 is hardcoded, which can be changed to options[index]
  });

 if(typeof milliseconds!=='undefined'){
     browser.sleep(milliseconds);
  }

 }

 module.exports =selectElement;
```

I am using a POM structure, so the dropdown method is in a separate `.js` file. I am calling this in my page file

```
 const methodDropDown = require('../BasePage/selectElements.js');


 var signUpBankDetails = function(){

    this.bankName = element.all(by.css('.form-group')).get(7).element(by.xpath("//label[text()='Select Bank Name']"));
   //the selector is clicked to open the drop down

  console.log("Start of this block =========>");

  this.selectDropDownMethod = function(){
     console.log("Drop Down method start ==========>");
     this.bankName.click();
     browser.sleep(1000);
     methodDropDown.selectElementDropdown(this.bankName,0,1000);

   };
```

I am getting the error which says -

```
   Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

The `this.bankName.click()` block is working fine because, I can see that the element is clicked and the drop down appears, however the selection seems to be erroring out. I have also attached the HTML snippet of code below -

[image]

PS- The webpage is using Angular2.

Comment: Would the error change if you would use `element.all(by.tagName('option')).get(2).click();` to click the option?

Comment: I already tried that, but I get an index out of bounds exception. My code which gets the elements via tagname seems to be not working- since the the error stated that there are 0 elements matching this locater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look at the HTML I see that the *label* is not containing the *select*. The select is in the `<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">..</div>` that is on the same level as the *label*.

When I look at you PO I see you are passing the *label* (`this.bankName`) as an *ElementFinder* with this `methodDropDown.selectElementDropdown(this.bankName,0,1000);`. The `methodDropDown.selectElementDropdown()` starts searching from the *ElementFinder* you pass and that is the `label`, not the `<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">..</div>` that holds the *select*.

Maybe you can change it into something this:

```
// Define ElementFinder for the bankname component
const bankNameComponent = $('p-dropdown[formcontrolename="bankname"]');
// Open the dropdown
bankNameComponent.$('label').click();
// Click on an element by index
bankNameComponent.$$('select option').get(2).click();
// Or search by text in the dropdown
bankNameComponent.element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'BNI')).click();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this doing something like this, but my code failed at the last two lines. I was not able to select the options using either the index or element selector method- it gave me a Element Not Visible Exception. The way I achieved this was to simulate a key press event (Keys.DOWN) in the last step.

Comment: @Deadpool, tnx for the reply and also with the solution that worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Solution 01

```
Select based on drop-down values attribute details
```

```
public selectOptionByValue(element: ElementArrayFinder,valueToSelect: string) : void{
        let clickedIndex: number;
        element.first().$$('option').filter(function(elem, index) {
            return elem.getAttribute("value").then(function(value) {
                if (value === valueToSelect) {
                    elem.click();
                    console.log('Yes ! Found option is:' + value);
                }
                return value === valueToSelect;
            });
        }).then(function (bool) {

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Ooops ! Error... '+err.message);
        });
    }
```

Solution 02

```
Select based on drop-down visible text details
```

```
public selectOptionByText(element: ElementArrayFinder,optionToSelect: string) : void{
        let clickedIndex: number;
        element.first().$$('option').filter(function(elem, index) {
            return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
                    if (text === optionToSelect) {
                        elem.click();
                        console.log('Yes ! Found option is:' + text);
                    }
                return text === optionToSelect;
            });
        }).then(function (bool) {

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Ooops ! Error... '+err.message);
        });
    }
```

Comment: it would be more helpful to readers if you were to explain the difference between your solutions, rather than just providing two similar-looking blocks of code with no commentary.

Comment: Solution 01: 4th line "return elem.getAttribute("value").then(function(value) {"    |||||  Solution 02 : 4th line "return elem.getText().then(function(text) {"

Comment: I can see the difference, but I think people will also be interested in the reason.